# Problem Migrating SQLite to MySQL using DBTNG module

Tags: 7, migrations

I need to convert a Drupal site that uses SQLite so it'll use MySQL instead. After some research I've found the [DBTNG module](https://www.drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) which does seem to fit the bill, however every time I try to migrate the dbs I get the following error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'An User Name' for key 'name'`

Please note that I have a large number of users in my site. When I tried to remove the aforementioned user and tried migrate again, I got the same error referring to a different user.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: How many duplicate usernames you have? And how you made Drupal accept that?

Comment: I don't know. The problem is that I've imported the users from a CSV that  allegedly had no duplicated (not the case). The problems now that I have tons of users that I do have to migrate.

Comment: Just *get* to know. And if (I suspect this might be the case) some of them never log in, you do not have to migrate them.